# Sequential Parse Promises running Cloud Function with varying input

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to make a sequential chain of Parse Promises with varying length and Cloud Function parameters like this:

```
var anArray = ['1', '2'];
var promise = new Parse.Promise.as();

for (var i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++) {
    promise = promise.then(
        function() {
            return Parse.Cloud.run('cloudFunc', {arg: anArray[i]});
        }
    )
}

promise.then(
    function(result) {
        // print result of last promise
    }
);

Parse.Cloud.define('cloudFunc', function(request, response) {
    response.success(request.params.arg);
});
```

This works well if the array only contains one element, however all subsequent Cloud Function calls is made with *arg = undefined*. Is there a way where I can get the intended functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect `i` reaches `2` as the `For` loop ends before most of your Cloud calls are resolved which means you are potentially sending `anArray[2]` as the parameter and that is clearly undefined. Replace your `For` loop with `forEach` instead to make sure that you send in the correct element of the array as the parameter for each call:

```
anArray.forEach(function(element) {
    promise = promise.then( function() {
        return Parse.Cloud.run('cloudFunc', {arg: element});
    });
});
```